# Modifying data in a list only if it is a select value

Tags: python

Hi guys i have a very long list of values, and what i want to do is loop though the list, and if the value is 200 or 20 then i want to modify the value with a value i have in a list

for example

i have a list

```
111010011010001101001111001110000011010011110011100000110000110000011101001100101111001111101001000001100110110111111100101000001100101111100011000011101101111000011011001100101100000110100110000011101111100001110111011101001000001110100110111110000011100111100101110010110000011010001101111111011110000011011011110101110001111010001000001100100110000111101001100001100000110001111000011101110100000110001011001011000001100001110010011001001100101110010010000011000011101110110010010000011010011110100100000111001111001011100101110110111100111000001101100110100111010111100101100000110000110000011011001101111111010010000011000111100001110111010000011000101100101
```

and what i want to do is search through my list to be modified and if it is a 200 or a 20 then since the first number of teh list above is a 1 then the 200 would be 201, then this process would carry on untill the modified value list above is finished

i have tried to compose a loop to do this :

```
x = 0
y = 0
for data in data:
  if data[x] == 200 or 20:
    data[x] = data[x] + text_to_be_hidden_binary[y]
    x = x + 1 
    y = y + 1
  else:
    x = x + 1
```

but i get the error

```
if data[x] == 200 or 20:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

i also do not think my method is the best method for doing this

Thanks

data = [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 20, 200, ........ etc ]
'

EDit:

```
L = list(binary)

x = 0
for i,v in enumerate(data) :
    if v==20 or v==200 :
        data[i]+= int(L[x])
        x = x + 1

    data[i]+= int(L[x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This seems to be working, is there a better way ?

```
x = 0
for i,v in enumerate(data) :
    if x < len(L):
        if v==20 or v==200 :
            data[i]+= int(L[x])
            x = x + 1
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you literally looking for the characters `'200'` or `'20'`? Or interpreting the binary substrings to find if they equal decimal `200` or `20`?

Comment: Sorry it is hard to explain, i am looking for the numbers 200 or 20 in a list, and if found i want to append the value with the value in my other list a 1 or a 0

Comment: yes its very unclear !is your data an int object ?

Comment: data is currently a list

Comment: Can you show us what the list `data` contains?

Comment: but your above data is a binary number !!!

Comment: data is added above, the binary number is another list of 1 and zeros i want to append to data so 200 would be 201 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say *the binary string is a lot smaller than the list* you can use this :

```
str= '111010011010001101001111001110000011010011110011100000110000110000011101001100101111001111101001000001100110110111111100101000001100101111100011000011101101111000011011001100101100000110100110000011101111100001110111011101001000001110100110111110000011100111100101110010110000011010001101111111011110000011011011110101110001111010001000001100100110000111101001100001100000110001111000011101110100000110001011001011000001100001110010011001001100101110010010000011000011101110110010010000011010011110100100000111001111001011100101110110111100111000001101100110100111010111100101100000110000110000011011001101111111010010000011000111100001110111010000011000101100101'


>>> data = [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 20, 200]
>>> for i,v in enumerate(data) :
...  if v==20 or v==200 :
...   data[i]+=int(str[i])
... 
>>> data
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 21, 201]
>>>
```

Note that `or` operation work on 2 statement ! you must write `if v==20 or v==200` be cause `if v== 200 or 20` is always `True` !

Comment: I don't think that's quite right if I understand OP's (unclear) question. You don't always add `1`, you either add `1` or `0` as you are walking along the string `'1110100110100...'` (I think).

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question,but yes cyber is right about the walking along 1110... number :)

Comment: is the len of your list and binary string equal ?

Comment: No the binary string is a lot smaller than the list, i have had a go at  modifying your code, but get an out of range error

Comment: so when they have not the same length how you want to add `1` ? can you explain more ? can you show me a bit of proper output ?

Comment: The idea is a bit of very basic steganography, i want to encode a message into an image, i only want to encode it to the green and once the binary list has ended, no more changes should be made

Comment: i edit the answer , try that with real list ! and give me the result !